# Would it be possible to perform a manual flip with my camera drone?

Tags: quadcopters, performance, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have a Snaptain SP510 camera drone. I haven't flown in a while, but I'm interested in getting back to it. After seeing some videos, I began to wonder if I'd be able to perform a manual flip. I know most camera drones weren't designed to flip, which is why this one doesn't have an automatic flip button, but I know some pilots can manually perform this aerial trick anyways. The SP510 is relatively compact and not too slow, but I wouldn't call it speedy either. Most websites I've looked at have discouraged performing flips with photography-focused drones (such as the DJI Mini 3 Pro). But is it still possible?

In addition, to perform a flip, would I need to change the drone's flight settings? Like many other modern quadcopters, the SP510 is connected to GPS, so it hovers in place by default. However, it does allow the pilot to turn on ATTI mode (which I've never tried before, but will be practicing). Would I have to use ATTI mode before attempting a flip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, ATTI mode only disables GPS, optical, and other positioning sensors. Your drone would still be actively stabilized with the Gyro and would still be limited in how far it can roll or pitch, making flips nearly impossible.

Unless your drone has ACRO or Manual flight modes, you won't be able to perform manual flips.